# Is my logic correct for Double pointers/Pointers in C for this example

Tags: c, pointers

> int  age;
>
> int  *p;
>
> int  **q;
>
> p=&age;
>
> q=&p;

For these set of variables, I'm trying to figure out the logic of how the pointers work w.r.t each other. I have coded it but I want to mentally be able to work out different scenarios using pointer logic which I am struggling with.

> **Case 1: age == *p**

So, a pointer points to a location in memory and stores the address of a variable. So, my thinking is that since p is a variable and *p stores it address and we also know that p=&age (p has address of age). So, *p ==age because they essentially have the same address.

> **Case 2: age == **q**

For this I drew a diagram.

I had *q stores address of **q and **q stores address of variable q. So, since variable q = &p and p = & age, so q=& age and thus making the statement age==*q true

> **Case 3: age == *q**

This is false but I'm not sure why. *q stores address of q which is the same as &p and since age is same as p which is same as q, it should be equal? I compiled it and its different but I dont see why though.

> **Case 4: p ==*q**

This again is True. q=&p so q* stores q's address which is basically the address of p.

This is how I see things for this question. Any guidance/correction on how to approach this and any flaws in my logic would help a lot.

Comment: I think you should change the way you are using the word "store".  It is not correct to say that "p is a variable and *p stores it address".  p is a variable.  Its value is the address of the thing it points to.  `*p` is a way of referencing the value of the variable that p holds the address of.

Comment: "q=&p so q* stores q's address which is basically the address of p." is not correct.  q stores the address of p, so `*q` is the value of p which is the address of `age`.

Comment: `*q` is not the value of `p`, it **is** (an alias) for `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > **Case 1: age == *p**
>
> So, a pointer points to a location in memory and stores the address of
>   a variable. So, my thinking is that since p is a variable and *p
>   stores it address and we also know that p=&age (p has address of age).
>   So, *p ==age because they essentially have the same address.

True, and your reasoning is essentially correct.  I would phrase the last bit differently, however: since `p` contains the address of `age`, it is necessarily the case that `*p` and `age` designate the same object.  That's what unary `*` does.  You could also say that for any identifier `x` that designates an object, `*&x == x`.

> > **Case 2: age == **q**
>
> For this I drew a diagram.
>
> I had *q stores address of **q and **q stores address of variable q.
>   So, since variable q = &p and p = & age, so q=& age and thus making
>   the statement age==*q true

True, and again your logic is essentially correct.  You might also argue that, by the same reasoning as in Case 1, it is true that `*q == p`.  From case 1, you know that `*p == age`, so we can combine those to say that `*(*q) == age`, which is the same as `**q == age`.

> > **Case 3: age == *q**
>
> This is false but I'm not sure why. *q stores address of [p] which is
>   the same as &p [...]

So far so good.

> [...] and since age is same as p

STOP! Flag on the play!  `age` is *not* the same as `p`.  It is the same as `*p`, which is quite different.

Suppose I write the street address of my house on a piece of paper.  Is the paper the same thing as the house?  Of course not.  In the same way, if I store the address of an object in a pointer variable, neither the pointer variable nor the pointer value stored in it is the same thing as the object to which the value points.

> > **Case 4: p ==*q**

True.  This the same as case 1.

Answer (score 0):

For case 4, you are trying to compare the value of age against the address of age.

Should be &age == *q or age==**q

You can try to print the value of the pointer against the address of age and you might understand further.